# How to insert webpage (form) field values into SQL Server using a recordset

Tags: sql-server, insert, html, recordset

I am working on a website which has a webpage/form upon which the user will enter typical customer data into the fields.
I would like to simply click the "Insert" button and insert the data from the fields into the database.
Specifically, I need to know/understand how to refer to the data in each field.

Fieldnames from the webpage:
- CustIDNumber
- CustFName
- CustLName
- CustAddr
- CustCity
- CustState
- CustZip

My idea of what the code may look like:

```
Protected Sub butSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butInsert.Click
 Dim connCust As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim reCust As new ADODB.REcordset
 Dim strSQL As String

 strSQL = "Insert Into CustomerDB (IDNum, FName, LName, Addr, City, State, Zip)
 strSQL = strSQL & "Values (CustIDNumber, CustFName, CustLName, CustAddr, CustCity, CustState, CustZip)

rsCUST = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsCUST.Open(sql, cnnWDBS)
rsCUST = cnnWDBS.Execute(strSQL)
rsCust.Close

End Sub
```

I'll likely embed this code in a `Try/Catch` block.
Am I on the right track here?  Am I referring to the webpage fields correctly?
Is there anything else that I should be checking for or doing?

Thanks in advance,

Rich

Comment: You need to use parameterized queries, or even better stored procedures for this type of thing. Your code is wide open to sql injection attack. NEVER directly execute data that comes from a webform.

Comment: +1 to Sean's suggestion on parameterized queries.  If this is ASP.NET use SqlClient instead of ADODB.  That will perform better and provide a richer programming model.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Don't do this. Listen to Dan Guzman below or Sean Lange above.

That looks like it should work. You'll need to reformat your string to concatenate all the variables properly.

```
strSQL = "Insert Into CustomerDB (IDNum, FName, LName, Addr, City, State, Zip) "
strSQL = strSQL & "Values ("& CustIDNumber & ", " & CustFName & "," &...& ")"
```

Comment: One should never build SQL Server statement strings by concatenating values from untrusted sources.  Instead, parameterized queries should be used, which have a number of benefits.

Comment: The practice of validating data is a good idea for data integrity but not so much for security.  Parameterized queries prevent injection entirely in SQL Server (barring dynamic SQL in a stored procedures).  Other benefits include plan reuse, no need to escape characters, avoid need for date formatting, decimal separators, etc.